# AVX512 or AVX2 vector permutations, group uint16 elements by strides of 16 (32 bytes)

Tags: x86-64, avx2, avx512

I have 64 two-byte (short) numbers in memory like this: 0 1 2 3 ... 63. I want to shuffle them so that they look like this in memory:

0 16 32 48 1 17 33 49 2 18 34 50 ... 15 31 47 63

What is the most effective way to do this using avx2 or avx512?

Comment: AVX-512 `vpermt2w` can do this in 2 instructions.  (But that instruction is 3 uops on SKX and even on Ice Lake, even though Ice Lake has more efficient `vpermb`).  So this might not be optimal.

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop?  What other operations is this between, e.g. should we minimize shuffle-port uops, overall front-end uops, or minimize latency?  Was the last store to this memory with 32 byte vectors, giving an advantage to that size of avoiding store-forwarding stalls?  Is it 64-byte aligned?  (If no, that makes ZMM vectors slightly less attractive, but probably still worth it.)

Comment: I am doing this in a loop (for 32 times on successive contiguous memory regions) -- there are no other operations in between. I can make it 64-byte aligned. So is avx512 vpermt2w/vpermb the best way to go?

Comment: It would be best to interleave this shuffle work with other work that can use the results, 
 especially if you can use the values while they're still in registers, but 32 iterations is few enough for out-of-order exec to overlap with some preceding and following work.  Anyway yeah, 2x `vpermt2w` per iteration to produce two 64-byte outputs from a pair of input vectors is the "obvious" way, especially since your loop means loading the two shuffle-control vectors will be amortized over the shuffles.

Comment: I don't see a cheaper way, although maybe something with blends could set up for different shuffles?  Still probably would cost more total uops, and the 3 uops from `vpermt2w` or `vpermt2b` aren't all for port 5 (one of them can run on port 0 instead).  https://uops.info/

Comment: How do you think this compares to using vpermw on ice lake (I am using ice lake btw)

Comment: maybe one vpermt2w and one vpermw

Comment: `vpermw` on ICL is still 2 uops, which is unfortunate.  The other interesting option is 1 uop `vpermb`, but I don't see a way to actually get the job done in fewer uops, since each output 64 bytes needs to grab bytes from across 128-bytes of input.  Like I said, perhaps with word blends from unaligned loads to avoid needing a shuffle?  But you need two such blends to set up for each shuffle, unlike with `vpermt2w` where a memory source operand is possible, or a register-copy.

Comment: yes vpermt2w is probably the way, especially if it supports memory source operands. (another important detail the intrinsics guide misses...) Too bad it only supports one memory operand, so probably will still need a load

Comment: You need two shuffles with the same two input vectors, so you *want* to do at least 1 separate load.  Probably 2 separate loads, because `vpermt2w` can't micro-fuse a memory source operand anyway.  It decodes to 4 uops with a memory source, up from 3 with a register source.  So 2x `vmovdqa32` aligned loads, `vmovdqa32` ZMM register copy (because vpermt2w has to destroy one of its 3 input registers, in this case one of the tables), then 2x `vpermt2w` (6 uops).

Comment: The reg copy takes a front-end uop but move-elimination means no back-end.  So 2x load uops, 1 mov, 2p05, 4p5, 2x stores = 11 total front-end uops, which can issue in just over 2 cycles, but take 4 cycles in the back-end for port 5 to keep up. So there's plenty of room for loop overhead and register copies without a front-end bottleneck.  Hyperthreading will hopefully let the other thread get useful work done on the other execution units.